# How to weave a 3rd party jar that is present in tomcat library folder using aspectj?

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, tomcat9, context.xml, load-time-weaving

I have tried weaving that 3rd party jar by putting it inside the projects lib folder and it worked correctly. But I want to weave that jar from the tomcat lib folder.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From the [The AspectJ Development Environment Guide](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/printable.html#classpathInpathAndAspectpath):

> In AspectJ tools, the inpath is where to find binary input - aspects and classes that weave and may be woven.